# NSIS Components page comes after the files has been installed?

Tags: installation, components, nsis, sections

I got this very odd issue with my NSIS installer, it is showing the components page/sections, after everything has been installed??

I haven't got this on an another installer of mine and I can't figure out what seems to be causing this..

Y.

EDIT:

Code:

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "SnapShot BK"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0.4"
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "DataAccess Europe"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "http://www.dataaccess.eu/"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\snapshotbk.exe"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

; MUI 1.67 compatible ------
!include "MUI.nsh"
!include "Sections.nsh"

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshot.ico"
!define MUI_UNICON "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshot.ico"

; Welcome page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

; License page
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\License Agreement.txt"

; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

;Variable for the icons_group
var ICONS_GROUP

;Start menu page
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_NODISABLE
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_DEFAULTFOLDER "SnapShot BK"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_ROOT "${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_KEY "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
!define MUI_STARTMENUPAGE_REGISTRY_VALUENAME "${PRODUCT_STARTMENU_REGVAL}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $ICONS_GROUP

; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

; Finish page
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME "$INSTDIR\readme.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Uninstaller pages
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_COMPONENTS

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------

page components
page instfiles

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
OutFile "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Setup.exe"
InstallDir "C:\Appl\SnapShot BK"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show
ShowUnInstDetails show

Section  "SnapShot BK AES" SEC01
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshotbk.exe"
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Snapshot BK.lnk" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Snapshot BK.lnk" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshot.ico"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\settings.sts"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\readme.txt"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\Exclude.txt"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\AES\AESauth.sts"
SectionEnd

Section  "SnapShot BK RC4" SEC02
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite ifnewer
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshotbk.exe"
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Snapshot BK.lnk" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\Snapshot BK.lnk" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\snapshot.ico"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\settings.sts"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\readme.txt"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\Exclude.txt"
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Yoshi\Desktop\Snapshot BK Installer\Files\RC4\RC4auth.sts"
SectionEnd

Section -AdditionalIcons
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "URLInfoAbout" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd


Function un.onUninstSuccess
  HideWindow
  MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "$(^Name) was successfully removed from your computer."
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  MessageBox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "Are you sure you want to completely remove $(^Name) and all of its components?" IDYES +2
  Abort
FunctionEnd

Section "Un.SnapShot BK AES" SE01
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Exclude.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\readme.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\settings.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshot.ico"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\AESauth.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Exclude.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\readme.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\settings.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshot.ico"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"

  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$DESKTOP\Snapshot BK.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Snapshot BK.lnk"

  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd

Section "Un.SnapShot BK RC4" SE02
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Exclude.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\readme.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\settings.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshot.ico"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\RC4auth.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Exclude.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\readme.txt"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\settings.sts"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshot.ico"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\snapshotbk.exe"

  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$DESKTOP\Snapshot BK.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK\Snapshot BK.lnk"

  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\SnapShot BK"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are shown in the order the statements `Page` or `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_xx` are listed

You have misplaced the components page:

```
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
```

Here the page for choosing the components will appear after the file installation progression.

Comment: Holy macaroni, yes I compared it with my other intsaller and you are right. Thanks Seki!